# Is it ok if I just delete a rails app directory? Will it leave any traces behind on the system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I just created some sample apps by running

```
rails new
```

command and then deleted the directory in which I created them after my work was done. Do I have to run some other command(s) to delete all the traces which rails could have left behind?

Comment: this should not be asked at stack overflow.

Comment: just deleting the folder should be fine, if you installed any gems and would like to get rid of them, you need to uninstall them manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the **local files**, you may have created a **database** and installed some **gems**.

To remove unused gems, run `gem cleanup`.

To purge the database, use `rake db:drop` in the project folder.

Files generated using `rails new` are local, and will be fully removed when you delete the folder. Running the command shows you which files were created.

```
$ rails new commandsapp
     create
     create  README.md
     create  Rakefile
     create  config.ru
     create  .gitignore
     create  Gemfile
     create  app
     ...
     create  tmp/cache
     ...
        run  bundle install
```