# How to clear old Rails local database when the repo has been deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails repo created locally for practice purposes. After I am done, I deleted the repo (all the folders), but I did not run `rails db:drop` before deleting the repo (it was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645941/10723457) that I should have dropped the db first). The rails projects are linked to postgres database locally. Is there a way to purge these orphaned database entries/data even if my deleted rails repo is gone?

Comment: Use the DB CLI to drop the database? The DB is a separate entity from the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Postgres [`dropdb` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-dropdb.html):

```
$ dropdb appname_test -i
$ dropdb appname_development -i
```

You may need to provide the connection details.